# Integrate 3D secure with Stripe in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I've been trying to implement 3D secure payments in my iOS app for a few days now and feel completely lost. Even though the SDK integrates this functionality, there seems to be very few mentions to it in the docs and even less on the forums out here.

I followed what's explained here in the official stripe docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/sources

and also on this tutorial:

https://www.hitchhq.com/stripe/activities/591b075c9659a6263d0ccd0e

But still couldn't get how to proceed exactly. Small precision, I was until now using tokens to charge my users and it works on production, but I now have to use sources for threedsecure.

Until now I've managed to show the confirmation view (both the test one or the one from my bank on production) and authorize the payment. But then I am always prompted a blank view only containing an ugly blue button saying "Go back to MyApp". I don't understand that, this is ugly and useless, and I guess I'm doing something wrong so that I get this right ? I would expect to be redirected to my app right after the user confirms his credit card.

Then, when the user authorized the credit card, I'm back in my app, and the docs say I have to call *startPollingSource* on the iOS side which will act as a hook to inform me when the charge is complete. On my server I should also implement a webhook which will get notified when the card is authorized and confirm the charge.
There I am completely confused, why can't I just send the source_id to my server and confirm the charge through this one simple call ? This double-hooks workflow makes no sense to me ..

Here I am, this doesn't work, and I guess I  missed something somewhere here.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to not try to implement stripe from scratch.Even though the integration is not that hard,they miss a lot of things in the documentation.

Better work on this sample project from their repo

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios